# Multiplying two Polynomials in a cpp LinkedList program

Tags: c++, linked-list, polynomial-math, singly-linked-list

I'm doing a Polynomials program in C++ that we're supposed to be implementing with a singly-linked list. And yes, this is a homework. I've worked out most of the program and I'm just stuck with my multiplication operator overloading. This is my operator* function:

```
LinkedList operator*(const LinkedList& a, const LinkedList& b)
{
    LinkedList product;
    Node* nodeA = a.head;
    Node* nodeB = b.head;
    int coeff, powr;

    if (nodeA == NULL && nodeB == NULL)
        return product;
    else if (nodeA == NULL && nodeB != NULL)
        return b;
    else if (nodeA != NULL && nodeB == NULL)
        return a;
    else {
        while (nodeA != NULL) {
            while (nodeB != NULL) {
                coeff = nodeA->getCoeff() * nodeB->getCoeff();
                powr = nodeA->getPow() + nodeB->getPow();
                product.addElement(coeff, powr);
                nodeB = nodeB->getNext();
            }
            nodeB = b.head;
            nodeA = nodeA->getNext();
        }
    }
    return product;
}
```

For reference, I just add a new element to the end of the Linked List for now.

Here is my AddElement function:

```
void LinkedList::addElement(int coeff, int powr)
{
    Node *newNode = new Node();

    // Set the Node's data
    newNode->setPowAndCoefficient(coeff, powr);
    newNode->setNextNode(NULL);
    Node *temp = head;

    if (temp != NULL) {
        // Go to the last element of the list
        while (temp->getNext() != NULL) {
            temp = temp->getNext();
        }
        // temp is now the last element and its next element is null
        // Set temp's next node to be the newNode
        temp->setNextNode(newNode);
    }
    else
        head = newNode;
}
```

Node is just my class with private data members coefficent, power and a pointer to the next node. LinkedList is my main class that includes a private Node* head member and public operator overloaded functions and several constructors. The constructor used here is the default constructor in which I just set the head to NULL.

I put some cout statments after the second while loop and I multiplied two polynomials to test my multiply function out.

So in this case, I have this code in my main.cpp file:

```
LinkedList poly1, poly2, result;
    // The first polynomial: 3x^3 + 7x^2 - 7
    poly1.addElement(3, 3);
    poly1.addElement(7, 2);
    poly1.addElement(-7, 0);
    cout << "Polynomial A: " << poly1 << endl;

    // The second polynomial: -5x^5 - 14x^3 + 7x^2 + 14
    poly2.addElement(-5, 14);
    poly2.addElement(-14, 3);
    poly2.addElement(7, 2);
    poly2.addElement(14, 0);
    cout << "Polynomial B: " << poly2 << endl;
```

Also, the << overloaded operator works fine and displays the linked list fine. 
The problem is when I try to do this:

```
result = poly1 * poly2;
```

I get a segmentation fault. And I don't know why. As I've said, I put cout statements inside the first while loop and this is what I get when I do poly1 * poly2:

```
 -15x^17 - 42x^6 + 21x^5 + 42x^3 - 35x^16 - 98x^5 + 49x^4 + 98x^2 + 35x^14 + 98x^3 - 49x^2 - 98
[1]    39009 segmentation fault  ~/Desktop/run
```

Yeah, it's pretty ugly, but this is before I add all these stuff together. But anyways, it's essentially right. I just get a segmentation fault after it evaluates the last constant.

I have no idea why it's doing this and it only does this for the multiply operator. Other stuff works fine though. I probably have a bug somewhere and I've looked for it these past few hours but I don't know what I've done wrong. Can someone please help?

Thanks.

My node class:

```
class Node {
private:
    int power;
    int coefficient;
    Node *next;
public:
    Node(); // in implementation: coeff = 0, power = 0, next = NULL;
    Node(const int coeff, const int powr = 1);
    void setPowAndCoefficient(const int coeff, const int powr);
    inline int getPow() const { return power; };

    inline int getCoeff() const { return coefficient; };

    inline void setNextNode(Node *aNode) { next = aNode; };

    inline Node *getNext() const { return next; };
};


Node::Node()
{
    coefficient = 0;
    power = 1;
    next = NULL;
}

Node::Node(const int coeff, const int powr)
{
    coefficient = coeff;
    power = powr;
    next = NULL;
}

void Node::setPowAndCoefficient(const int coeff, const int powr)
{
    coefficient = coeff;
    power = powr;
    next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Are those the simplest polynomials that cause the error?

Comment: You haven't shown enough code to pinpoint a problem. The code you have provided is fine. (See: http://ideone.com/AePLI).

Comment: @user315052 Well, I could add more code but as I've said, this is the only piece of code that's actually causing an error. Everything else is fine. Plus, if you ignored everything except the operator* function, the Node class (which is pretty simple) and the LinkedList default constructor (which just has "head = NULL" in it), add the cout statement in the first while loop, and run the code, it will produce a segmentation fault after the constant which is what I'm getting.

Comment: @Beta well if I just have the first poly1 term (poly1.addElement(3, 3);) and the poly2 term as poly2.addElement(-5, 14); and then do poly1 * poly2, the code works fine and I get -15x^17 without the segmentation fault. But when I add the second term to poly1 or poly2, it produces a segementation fault.

Comment: Okay then, I posted my Node class. And I do return the ostream object. I do have the code cout << poly1<< endl and that prints the polynomial as Polynomial A: 3x^3 + 7x^2 - 7 which is fine. I just think there's something wrong with my multiplication function since the rest of my program works fine.

Comment: @user315052 Sorry, I just edited it in to my post just now.

Comment: Can you run the program in `gdb` and determine where the segmentation fault occurs? http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/

Comment: @watabou: Can you demonstrate the crash on ideone?

Comment: @Geoff_Montee wow nice, gdb actually helped. Definately going to be using that in the future. Thanks. It says it could not access memory and I'm confused as to why. This is what it says right after I do poly1 * poly2: Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000008
0x0000000100001bb4 in Node::setNextNode (this=0x0, aNode=0x100103b40) at Node.h:56
56          inline void setNextNode(Node *aNode) { next = aNode; };

Comment: @watabou: This usually means you did not recompile all the source files that needed recompiling after you changed your header file.

Comment: The `this=0x0` is probably it. `0x0` is `NULL`.

Comment: @Geoff_Montee: Alright, okay. So I'm setting the nextNode but that nextNode is null right? Is that what it means? Can you please pinpoint where that actually is? That problem only occurs on the multiply function so I'm assuming I'm setting the nextNode but the next Node is null?

Comment: Well the command I'm using is "clang++ Node.cpp LinkedList.cpp main.cpp -o polyRun && ./polyRun" and I'm saving every source file before compiling. It's a weird error but at least now I know exactly where the error is. Now all I have to do is figure out why I'm getting that error in the first place

Comment: A long shot: what happens if you have just `poly1 * poly2;`, and *not* `result = poly1 * poly2;`? Maybe it's the assignment that's the problem. Have you written an assignment operator?

Comment: Okay it works fine in g++. I don't know why so I'm just going to go with that. I have no idea why it doesn't work in clang++. If anyone has an idea as to what exactly is happening, I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: @Beta Actually, I did try that many times before but it still gave me a segmentation fault. I know I kept thinking it was maybe my copy constructor that had a bug. But it was just clang misbehaving. And no I haven't written an assignment operator. Should I?

Comment: I don't think it mattered though. If I just have poly1 * poly2 and just have the cout statement in the function to output the product, it still gave me a segmentation fault.

Comment: Well, if you post the `LinkedList` class we can take a crack at it.

Answer (score 2):

Dude,
I was kinda too lazy to read through the whole post.. 
But here's how I would multiply two polynomials ..

```
    LinkedList operator*(const LinkedList& a, const LinkedList& b){
int coef,pow;
LinkedList temp = new LinkedList();
    for(node * a1 = a->head;a1!=NULL;a1=a1->next)
    for(node * b1 = b->head;b1!=NULL;b1=b1->next){
     coef = a1->getCoeff() * b1-> getCoeff();
     pow = a1->getPow()+b1->getPow();
node ab  = new node(coef,pow);//Writting it java style, cant remember if this is how u       //declare objects in c++ :(
temp.addNode(ab);
}
return temp;
}
```

I am sorry if it doesn't help you .. But I am trying to just present you an idea.